# Python accessing element inside array inside json

Tags: json, python-3.x

Can someone help me to access myapp from below json using python, please ?

```
{
    "Data": {
        "Name": "myname",
        "AccountName": "test",
        "classic": [
          {
            "cName": "mycname",
            "tags": ["tag1", "tag2"],
            "Version": "1.14.10",
            "app": "myapp"
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `json.load` for reading a file or `json.loads` for a string.

```
data_dict = json.loads(your_data)
print(data_dict["Data"]["classic"][0]["app"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use json loads to parse a json string and json dumps for stringifying the json to a json string

Here in your case you will need json loads

```
input = {
    "Data": {
        "Name": "myname",
        "AccountName": "test",
        "classic": [
          {
            "cName": "mycname",
            "tags": ["tag1", "tag2"],
            "Version": "1.14.10",
            "app": "myapp"
        }
        ]
    }
}

parsed_input = json.loads(input)
output  = parsed_input["Data"]["classic"][0]["app"]
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use json library for the same.

```py
input_json= {
    "Data": {
        "Name": "myname",
        "AccountName": "test",
        "classic": [
          {
            "cName": "mycname",
            "tags": ["tag1", "tag2"],
            "Version": "1.14.10",
            "app": "myapp"
        }
        ]
    }
}


data = json.loads(input_json)

result=data["Data"]["classic"][0]["app"])
```

Comment: The code is a little difficult to read, could you use a codeblock so that its easier on the eyes?

Comment: Does this help?